# Can a node promise chain fail to execute synchronously?

Tags: node.js, promise

If I have a sequence of promises/function as example below, is it still possible that functions would resolve out of sequence? I have one function that is a mongoose query and update then another sends the data to a view. My view is loading but is not reflecting the correct results of the mongoose query results.

```
let function_one(data) = function(){
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {  
    {do stuff...    
      resolve('howdy');
    }
  });
};

let function_two(some_data) = function(){
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {  
    {  do stuff...    
    resolve('howdy');
    }
  });
};  

let function_three(some_data) = function(){
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {  
    {do stuff...    
      resolve('howdy');
    }
  });
};  

let function_four(some_data) = function(){
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {  
    {do stuff...    
      resolve('howdy');
    }
  });
};  

function_one(data).then(function(result){
  return function_two(result);
}).then(function(result){
  return function_three(result);
}).then(function(result){
  return function_four(result);
}).then(function(result){
  console.log(result);
}).catch(err => console.log("Caught " + err));
```

Here's the code I have put together: It is as if "res.json({status: 200, data: result});" is being executed before the mongoose find completes?

```
let gettheinformation =  function(invoicelist3){
    return new Promise(  function(resolve, reject) {
        // console.log(invoicelist3);
            Product.aggregate([
                {
                    $match: {
                        Priced: true
                    }
                }
                ,
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$Invoice",
                        pricedcount: {$sum: 1}
                    }
                }
            ], function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });
    });
};


let getinvprodspriced =  function(invlist){
    return new Promise(  function(resolve, reject) {
           // console.log(invlist);
        for(var oo = 0; oo < invlist.length; oo++){
        Invoicestatus.update({Invoice:invlist[oo]._id}, {Noofitemspriced: invlist[oo].pricedcount}, {upsert: true},  function (err) {}); 
        }
        resolve(invlist);
        });
};

let getinvprodcount = function(invprodcount){
        return new Promise(  function(resolve, reject) {
    Product.aggregate([
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: "$Invoice",
                        pradcount: {$sum: 1}
                    }
                }
            ], function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                  // console.log(result);
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });

    });
}


let saveinvprodcount =  function(invprodcount){
    return new Promise(  function(resolve, reject) {
        for(var ok = 0; ok < invprodcount.length; ok++){
        Invoicestatus.update({Invoice:invprodcount[ok]._id}, {Noofitems: invprodcount[ok].pradcount}, {upsert: true},  function (err) {}); 
        }
        resolve(invprodcount);
        });
};

let getarrdocs =  function(result){
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        Invoicestatus.find({}, function(err, docs){
          resolve(docs); 
        });       
    });
};

router.get('/fetcharrdata', function(req, res) {


    gettheinformation().then(function(result){
      return getinvprodspriced(result);
    }).then(function(result){
      return getinvprodcount(result);
    }).then(function(result){
      return saveinvprodcount(result);
    }).then( function(result){
      return getarrdocs(result);
    }).then(function(result){


        res.json({status: 200, data: result});


    }).catch(err => console.log("Caught " + err));

});
```

Comment: No, the functions will resolve in sequence. It will be better to answer if you add the actual code.

Comment: no they will resolve in a sequence, because once the first one is resolved, you call the second one and once the second is resolved, you call the third one. so it'll run in a sequence, unless there's an error because if there is it'll abort. also if you wanna avoid chaining these promises, you can use async await to get them in the right order.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have added the code I have put together. Is there any way that the promise chain is ending prior to the mongoose query completing?

Comment: What is the nature of 'Invoicestatus.update' funtion, if it returns a promise then you are using it in wrong way. and second thing dont console.log your errors, use reject(error)

Comment: Ivoicestatus.update is there to update respective field values within the collection Invoicestatus. Is it looking wrong?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about my question, is 'Invoicestatus.update' synchronous or async, what is its return type , a promise or a value? @B.Sabz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in saveinvprodcount methods for loop, function will resolve before execution of Invoicestatus.update function,

```
let saveinvprodcount =  function(invprodcount){
return new Promise(  function(resolve, reject) {
    for(var ok = 0; ok < invprodcount.length; ok++){
    Invoicestatus.update({Invoice:invprodcount[ok]._id}, {Noofitems: invprodcount[ok].pradcount}, {upsert: true},  function (err) {}); 
    }
 //this will resolve before completion of Invoicestatus.update
    resolve(invprodcount);
    });
};
```

First promisify update function then use an array to hold promises and You can use promise.all to execute all promises at once. See below

```
 let saveinvprodcount = function (invprodcount) {
 let promises = [];
 for (var ok = 0; ok < invprodcount.length; ok++) {
     promises.push(updateData(invprodcount[ok]));
 }
 return Promise.all(promises);
 };

 let updateData = function (invProd) {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    Invoicestatus.update({ Invoice: invProd._id },
        { Noofitems: invProd.pradcount }, { upsert: true }, function (err) {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve();
        });
     });
   };
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ganesh, I will try this out!

Comment: @B.sabz let me know if it works or any other problem comes

Comment: Thank you Ganesh, that worked man! The only thing was "promises.push(updateData(invprodcount(ok)));" should have been "promises.push(updateData(invprodcount[ok]));". I did the same for getinvprodspriced and it's now 100%. Many thanks, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do. by using `Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])` to let them running asynchronously and get the result at once. However, in this case, the result of the first call is the input, you need to wait for it before running the second one. So that, you have to run in sequence (because of the business logic, not the nature of the language.